# Fpdf se habra en una ventana nueva

Tags: php, fpdf

mi pdf se crea correctamente pero lo que quiero es que se habra en una ventana nueva 
Este es mi codigo pero me lo habre en una pestaña nueva y no en una ventana

```
   <input type="submit" Value="Ver Reporte" name="" class='btn btn-success'  onClick="document.formulario.action='verPDF.php'; document.formuario.submit()"  ;>
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes simular un botón con el elemento **HTML** `<a>` para lograrlo. Por qué utilizar `<a>`? Porque posee una propiedad denominada `target` que te permite entre otras cosas lograr lo que quieres que es generar el documento desde otra ventana en tu navegador. La propiedad `target="_blank"` indica que se ejecute tu código javascript del `onClick` en una nueva pestaña del navegador.

Para ello transformas tu input en el siguiente código:

```
<a type="button" href="#" value="Ver Reporte" target="_blank" class='btn btn-success'  onClick="document.formulario.action='verPDF.php'; document.formuario.submit();"></a>
```

Después mediante **CSS** puedes eliminar el color azul de la letra por ser un link, el subrayado, entre otras cosas que no te gusten.

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!